# Why if i created a mock i am still getting error?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

i am doing testing, i made a test in that test i create a mock for a fake function

```
jest.mock('@/services/myService', ()=>({getAvailables: jest.fn().mockReturnValue()}))
```

that function is running in my component

```
 onMounted(async () => {
        const answer = await getAvailables1()
        const answer = await getAvailables2()
        const answer = await getAvailables3()
```

but still i am getting this error

(node:81921) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: (0 , _ContractService.getAvailables1) is not a function
(node:81921) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag

if i put like this first getAvailables2

```
 onMounted(async () => {
            const answer = await getAvailables2()
            const answer = await getAvailables1()
```

i am getting this error
(node:81921) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: (0 , _ContractService.getAvailables2) is not a function

if i put like this first getAvailables3

```
 onMounted(async () => {
            const answer = await getAvailables3()
            const answer = await getAvailables2()
```

i am getting this error
(node:81921) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: (0 , _ContractService.getAvailables3) is not a function

also i try with `mockResolvedValue`, does not worked

```
export const getAvailables = async () => {
  let response
  let error
  try {
    response = await getData()
  } catch (err) {
    error = err
    throw err
  }
  return { response, error }
}
```

Comment: To be able to help, I'd have to see what you're trying to mock and how your mock currently looks like. The complete error message would also be helpful. Your mock currently calls `getData()`. What is `getData`? Is it returning a promise?

Comment: @Tao but i am trying to mock that function

Comment: @tao i updated my question see again please please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want a [mock partial](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-partials):

```js
jest.mock('@/services/myService', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('@/services/myService');

  return {
    __esModule: true,
    ...originalModule,
    getAvailables1: () => Promise.resolve({ foo: 'bar' }),
    getAvailables2: () => Promise.resolve({ foo: 'baz' }),
    getAvailables3: () => Promise.resolve({ foo: 'bad' }),
    /* any other method of your service that gets called */
  };
});
```

This will mock the provided functions in the mock while the rest of the service will function as in the original.

Comment: does not worked it, do you have another solution?

Comment: Nope. I need more context. I have to be able to see what you're testing, run and debug it. You're basically not showing enough for anyone to figure out the cause. *"Doesn't work"* has no real meaning for anyone trying to help you.

Comment: i updated my question see again please ple

Comment: First of all, it's not an error. It's a warning. Secondly, the warning is clear: it is happening when `_ContractService.getAvailables1` is run. In your mock, you have only mocked `getAvailables`. You have also add `getAVailables1` method to the mock.

Answer (score 1):

`getAvailables()` is async function that always returns a promise.

So, in order to mock that function you need to return the mock promise with success or rejected value.

Following is the example of mocking that function which returns success promise.

```
jest.mock('@/services/myService', () => ({
   getAvailables: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(true)
}))
```

Comment: i am still getting the error

Comment: Is it the same error?

Comment: yes i still getting the same error, i had 4 error for 4 functions, with your help now i am getting 3 errors

Comment: Would be helpful if you add the snippet for your test and how you handle getAvailables promises in your js code?

Comment: i made a update in my question

Comment: You cannot have `throw` in catch clause. Try removing `throw err`